# camera calibration using charuco boards

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, aruco

I am working on camera calibration task using Charuco patterns using OpenCV, this is the first time i deals with this kind of boards but the problem that the corners_ids after interpolation step results the whole corners which is 70 corner in my case but the ids (0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60) aren't accurate, i don't know exactly the failure but i doubt that the board i have created using cv2.aruco.CharucoBoard.create(squaresX, squaresY, squareLength, markerLength, dictionary) is not acuurate, therefore i need someone familiar with it to understand me these parameters refer to especially (squareLength, markerLength).

[this the input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv37n.jpg) [provided images after interpolation id(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60) each surrounded by black circle which positioned in an inaccurate location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO7hU.jpg)

```
def calibrate_charuco(dirpath, image_format, marker_length, square_length):
    '''Apply camera calibration using aruco.
    The dimensions are in cm.
    '''
    criteria = (cv2.TermCriteria_EPS + cv2.TermCriteria_MAX_ITER, 100, .001)
    aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_4X4_1000)
    board = aruco.CharucoBoard.create(11,8,square_length, marker_length, aruco_dict)
    
    counter, corners_list, id_list = [], [], []
    img_dir = pathlib.Path(dirpath)
    first = 0
    i = 0
    # Find the ArUco markers inside each image
    impaths = img_dir.glob(f'*{image_format}')
    for img in impaths:
        image = cv2.imread(str(img))
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        corners, ids, rejected = aruco.detectMarkers(img_gray, aruco_dict)
        for corner in corners:
            cv2.cornerSubPix(img_gray, corner, (3, 3), (-1, -1), criteria)
        resp, charuco_corners, charuco_ids = aruco.interpolateCornersCharuco(corners, ids, img_gray, board, minMarkers=0)
        aruco.drawDetectedCornersCharuco(image, charuco_corners, charuco_ids, (255, 125, 125))
        # If a Charuco board was found, let's collect image/corner points
        # Requiring at least 20 squares
        if resp > 20:
            # Add these corners and ids to our calibration arrays
            corners_list.append(charuco_corners)
            id_list.append(charuco_ids)
        
    # Actual calibration
    ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = aruco.calibrateCameraCharuco(
        charucoCorners=corners_list, 
        charucoIds=id_list, 
        board=board, 
        imageSize=img_gray.shape, 
        cameraMatrix=None, 
        distCoeffs=None)
    
    return [ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs]

# Parameters
IMAGES_DIR = 'Cam1'
IMAGES_FORMAT = 'jpg'
# Dimensions in cm
MARKER_LENGTH = 0.8
SQUARE_LENGTH = 1


ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = calibrate_charuco(IMAGES_DIR, IMAGES_FORMAT, MARKER_LENGTH, SQUARE_LENGTH)
print(mtx)
original = cv2.imread('Cam1/G0011233.jpg')
dst = cv2.undistort(original, mtx, dist, None, mtx)
cv2.imwrite('undist_charuco.jpg', dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you used the last version of opencv (4.6.0.66), in which it seems interpolateCornersCharuco is not rendering correct results. Uninstalling and reverting to 4.1.2.30 made it work for me :

```
python3 -m pip install opencv-python==4.1.2.30
python3 -m pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.2.30
python3 -m pip install opencv-python-headless==4.1.2.30
```